Screen dims then beeps once per minute while charging
I'm experiencing an issue where exactly every 60 seconds, the screen briefly dims, then brightens, then beeps. I don't care about the dimming/brightening, but the beeping is maddening.
It happens while charging using a new (non-Apple) Magsafe3 connector I bought, connected to a 96W Apple power adaptor. This combo otherwise seems to charge fine.
So: can I fix this behaviour? Or at the least, prevent the beeping?
It's a 2022 M2 Max Macbook Pro. Ventura 13.6.3 (22G436)
EDIT
After some research I've discovered:

the screen dimming behaviour can be disabled in settings, "Slightly dim the display on battery"
the beep is called the "Power chime".

So now the question is how to disable the power chime. The actual file is at /System/Library/CoreServices/PowerChime.app/Contents/Resources/connect_power.aif but I'm not able to modify/remove it.

Ok, so to disable the screen dimming, uncheck "Slightly dim the display on battery" in settings.
To disable the power chime, in a terminal run:
killall PowerChime
defaults write com.apple.PowerChime ChimeOnNoHardware 1
defaults write com.apple.PowerChime ChimeOnAllHardware 0

As for why this cable causes macOS to think the power has been reconnected every minute...who knows.

I would suggest checking the power subsystem's console logs. I remember seeing similar info in iPhone's sysdiagnose.

This is just masking some underlying problem — a problem which may not be causing other visible effects, but might still be having an adverse effect on things such as battery health/life.  This would also prevent those notifications when power is removed.

True, but I'm really not sure that I need an audible notification in those cases.

You may be seeing an example of the problem described here:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255123412
and
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255743439

Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.
